# Get Last 3 days data from table CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get the last 3 days' data from the table with this query

```
$this->db->where('booking_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND NOW()');
```

but my problem is the booking date is in UNIX timestamp like this 1600811452.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` gives you current Unix timestamp. Calculate the number of seconds that exists on a day. Multiply by 3. Subtract from `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. There you have the start date. `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is the end date.

Or

```
$this->db->where('booking_date BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())');
```